# Instantly Update Text On Button

Tags: button, insert-update

I am having trouble updating the text on the button instantly. It's always updating one input behind. What's the best way to get instant results as you insert data?

```
public void getTenPercent(){
    Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
    double tithe = 0.00;
    while(res.moveToNext()){
        if(!res.getString(1).equals(""))
            tithe += Double.parseDouble(res.getString(1)) / 10;
    }
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
    btnDelete.setText("$" + String.valueOf(tithe));
    res.close();
}
```

It doesn't matter where I try to implement getTenPercent(), before, after or even before and after it still updates it one input behind.